# rendering templates from dynamically created folders in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple flask application where the user selects a city and the type of restaurant they are interested in.  I generate a folium map and save the map as html.

I render the map in my hmtl iframe.

It works well when the map is saved in the templates folder.

But I want to save the files under the city folder inside the template folder.  When I do this the map is not rendered.

Here is the file structure I am looking at

```
--flaskwebsite
----main.py
----map.py
----templates
------xxxxx #dynamically created based on the city selected
--------xxxxmap.html
```

Here is the my code

```
@app.route('/neighmap/<neighfile>')
def neighmap(neighfile):
    return render_template(neighfile)
```

Where neighfile is the path to the html file.  If the file is simple xxxxmap.html and stored in the templates folder it renders.  But when i set neighfile to '/NewYorkCity/nyc-neigh.hmtl' it does not work, where NewYorkCity is folder under templates.

Comment: `hmtl` is not a valid template language. The correct filename extension is `.html`

Answer (score 0):

The template path is relative to the path specified as `template_path` while initializing the app. For example as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
```

Therefor just removing the trailing slash should do the job:

```
@app.route('/neighmap/<neighfile>')
def neighmap(neighfile):
    return render_template('NewYorkCity/nyc-neigh.hmtl')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, the `neighfile` parameter of the `neighmap` function is a path to the file under the templates folder.

You need to add the datatype for the parameter `neighfile`, like this:

```
@app.route('/neighmap/<path:neighfile>')
```

The reason that you're not getting the file is when you pass in the path with a `/`  without specifying its datatype, python will only take the characters before the `/` as the parameter passed into the function, and what's after the `/` will be recognized as another path of your application. By adding specifying the `path` you are telling the program to escape the `/` characters so it would be read correctly.

According to the documentation:

| Type | What Flask Does |
| --- | --- |
| `string` | (default) accepts any text without a slash |
| `path` | like `string` but also accepts slashes |

You can read more about flask variable types on the Flask documentation [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your guidance.  I found it was easier to store the folium maps as HTML in the static folder and display them  It worked fine.

Comment: Hi @NarayanaBandhi, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution to your question. There is no obligation to do this.